# Is it possible to generate a thumbnail of an object (e. g. a shape) in a Google Slides File with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

With the [Slides API getThumbnail](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail) it is possible to generate a thumbnail of a specific slide/page (`pageObjectId`) of a specific presentation (`presentationId`):

```
GET https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}/pages/{pageObjectId}/thumbnail
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get a thumbnail of a specific object, for example a shape (not the whole slide/page). I know the `ObjectId` and of course the `pageObjectId` and `presentationId`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to obtain the thumbnail of a specific object using that method because you are going to get the following error if you use the object ID of something that is not a page:

> The specified object with pageObjectId "your object ID" is not a page.

A possible workaround would be to create an additional blank page within the same document or in a new one, then copy the shape to it, and change the shape size to cover the whole page, and then delete it, that way when you get the thumbnail of the page you will only see the exact same shape you created.

In case you want to do it for images, you can "create" your own thumbnail by using the `presentations.pages.get` and modify the size parameter of the `contentUrl` from the response.

An example of the contentUrl would be [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WV2wkOJIOdS7MnNF-kNw_WcTQ3uVABxcZ0rdXDU9sfRQjnAStVtAUOII2bvoRRes4DgQc6WopVKgXgPZq5EHgqN_QxJV8l-YLVw4JhNoaGCz5rHyA_pLpAPteWFChds8hMg8tJYTe4ow2IAK0791Jf9Hq6RrEk0=s2048). If you check the URL you will see that the size parameter can be found at the end like `s=2048`, however you can modify that number to get the size you prefer, for example [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WV2wkOJIOdS7MnNF-kNw_WcTQ3uVABxcZ0rdXDU9sfRQjnAStVtAUOII2bvoRRes4DgQc6WopVKgXgPZq5EHgqN_QxJV8l-YLVw4JhNoaGCz5rHyA_pLpAPteWFChds8hMg8tJYTe4ow2IAK0791Jf9Hq6RrEk0=s250), I only changed the parameter to `s=250`.

Just note that the default lifetime of that URL is 30 minutes and would only work for images, not for shapes.

#### References:

- [Page element: Images](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/images#Page.Image)
- [presentations.pages.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/get)